# Need to understand behind scenes | node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, joyent

I would like to know, how can I write something(small) like node in native lanuage(c,cpp). I read that c,c++ experts developed node.js and made it available with javascript interface. This interface is much much simpler to start with node.js applications.

This is not about re-inventing the wheel,(only learning) but I want to learn/understand the way where to start if I want to create a server that work like node, it is not performance or scalability or simplicity oriented. nothing like that.

Any book or any c,cpp topic that will help me to start with websockets, broadcasting data and such important features of node. I am new to c,cpp also but need to understand what is making node such a strong technology.

Any other solutions than taking source code of node.js ?

Comment: Another project you might be interested in is [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)(pronounced engine-x). It's an open-source event based web server also written in C/C++. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/git-mirror/nginx)

Comment: @BrandonBoone : thanks for the reply, but how can I write c,cpp servers more stronger than writing only chat servers. ?

Comment: The source code is available for all of Node.JS. I'm not clear why you wouldn't want to start there.  Asking for books/tutorials/etc. isn't a good match for StackOverflow.

Comment: @WiredPrairie : yeah, thanks ! node.js source code. In future I will take care of question and will not ask for books/tutorials references.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is powered by [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) - it's an asynchronous crossplatform io library, written in C. Basically, it does everything node does, but exposes only C interfaces.